# Prevent Onchange event triggering on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Onchange event, it's working fine. But i want it to prevent trigger on page load.

```
$("#first").change(function(){
   $("#salary").val(function () {
    return $(this).find('option').filter(function () {
      return $(this).prop('null');
        }).val();
 });
});
```

Can anyone help to achieve this with this code?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is unclear.  Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is unclear here?

Comment: For example, what did you mean with this phrase: *event triggering on page load*.  The code you've shared doesn't trigger anything, just bind the change event.

Comment: The code you write will not trigger on page load but on change of #first. So what is your problem ?

Comment: @Ele Maybe he is changing the value on page load and its getting triggered. But still, you must be very clear on this Zain.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao it makes sense, but as you said the OP must be clear.

Comment: @Abdullah Shoaib it is triggering on page load no idea why.

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao  i will take care next time what i want to achieve in my question.

Comment: @zain i have test your code,it is not triggering on page load. Can you show your full html+javascript code ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$( window ).on( "load", function() {
   $("#first").change(function(){
    $("#salary").val(function () {
      return $(this).find('option').filter(function () {
        return $(this).prop('null');
        }).val();
    });
  });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read in this url https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/, and resolve.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
      console.log( "document loaded" );
  });

  $( window ).on( "load", function() {
      console.log( "window loaded" );
  });
  </script>
 </head>
</html>
```